# How do I show feed from Blogger into HTML5 website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, feedburner

I've been using **feedwind** in my HTML5 website to show the content of my blog in Blogger, but for some reason is not showing main images. So I'm looking for an alternative that works.

To put the Blogger URL into an Iframe is not the way I like, because I want to show individual posts into a carrousel mode (or similar). I've been looking in Google and CodeCanyon, but most of jQuery RSS feed readers scripts are from 2010 up to 2013. Most of them are not working at all.

Is there any working script in JS/JQuery that parse the Feed and show the last 10 posts?

Thanks for reading!

*(PD= I appreciate the advice to migrate website into Wordpress, yet sounds pretty good but is not a quick&easy alternative in this moment).*

Comment: the X in AJAX means XML, you dont need a lib. show your code and what you have tried (working or not)

Comment: Check here: https://feed.mikle.com/signup/
This app is actually running in the web but not working well (not showing main image).

Comment: You may just need to add absolute paths to the images in your feed/blog rather than relative. I don't feel inclined to sign up to a site to look at your feed, bit odd.. without going down the rabbit hole, the service seems like a consolidator service which bundles pages/posts into one feed to put on a site. ok all them site you fetch from have API's (Facebook,Twitter,Google Calendar,Instagram) you could make your own scrapper/combiner by using their apis, which are well documented. RSS on the other hand is "built-in" to javascript as mentioned, clients could do the fetch with ajax